# To be X minutes from VERB-ing" correct?

Tags: grammaticality

Is this sentence grammatically correct? "**I was 5 minutes from finishing watching the movie.**"

Can i construct similar sentences using "From", like 
"**He was minutes from calling me when he lost his phone.**" 
Or

"**She was minutes from finishing her homework**"

Would that be grammatically correct, if i used the sentence i used for examples?

Comment: Please avoid using such a vague title. A good title allows us to understand your question with just a quick glance over the title.

Comment: Also, please add your idea about what you think is wrong with the sentence. You're here long enough to have heard "Details, please!", I believe.

Comment: Agreed. The title should be like a newspaper headline...  not the whole question, just something that attracts the reader's attention and gives some information about the question. For the question itself, you should give a bit more information- for example, a situation in which this sentence might be used, similar sentences that you have seen, and what you think might be wrong with this sentence.

Comment: Um... that's a very boring newspaper headline. How many questions do you think there are that say "Is this grammatically correct?".  Lots and lots and lots. Why should I look at your question, rather than any of the others? Explain in the title what's different about your question.

Comment: Your second example *(He was minutes from calling me)* is idiomatically extremely unlikely, because this construction is only really appropriate in contexts where the subject is ***close to doing/achieving something*** that they are (and *have* been, usually for some time) working towards. So in your example we're forced to conjure up a context where "he" has spent some time agonizing about making the call, then mysteriously *loses* his phone just when he's plucked up the courage to use it.

Comment: You could title your question *Is "to be X minutes from VERB-ing" correct?*, or maybe *Grammar and usage of "I was X minutes from doing something"*, or something like that. Being specific is important not only for attracting answers, but also because when another user writes their own question the page will automatically look for questions with similar titles. If those titles reflected accurately the content of the post, there would be less duplicates.

Comment: My bad, i'll try not to repeat my mistakes from here on forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sentence would sound like a native speaker in all of your examples.

> "He was minutes from calling me when he lost his phone."

The only reason this sentence is a little awkward is that it's missing the amount of minutes.

> "He was **5** minutes from calling me when he lost his phone."

Sounds like a normal English sentence.

Other than that, your sentences are fine!

Comment: Why doesn't the original sentence work? Why does it matter if the exact “amount of minutes” isn't specified? What does “to be minutes from” mean? Also, would “to be X minutes away from _gerund_” be _even_ more natural?

Comment: The original sentence, "I was 5 minutes from finishing watching the movie." works just fine! An amount of time (5 minutes) was specified, which makes the sentence work and seem natural. The sentence I was saying was awkward is "She was minutes from finishing her homework." The sentence *does* work, because you are saying she is close to finishing her homework (she only has minutes left, as opposed, for instance, to hours). However, specifying *how many* minutes (example: 5 minutes) she was away from completing homework makes it more simple to understand.

I hope that helps!

Comment: @redjax 

Say, would the sentence " She was minutes from finishing her homework." be completely incorrect?
Or is it just a tad bit vague when don't put in how much time, or in this case minutes you're talking about, but not totally incorrect?

Comment: @lekonchekon That sentence is correct. This is one of those intricacies in English that makes me feel bad for people trying to learn it! It makes more sense to specify a time, example "she was **5** minutes from finishing her homework," because that gives an exact end time for the homework. However, saying "she was minutes from finishing her homework" also makes sense, it just does not specify how many minutes actually remain on the homework. It would make more sense to say "she is almost done with her homework" in this situation. I hope this helps, because it's definitely a complicated one!

Comment: Thanks.
And i totally understand where you're coming from, it's just that i watch a lot of movies and stuff, and when i see someone in the show i'm watching use a construction i've never seen anyone use before, i just can't help, but get a bit curious.

Comment: @lekonchekon don't be sorry! English has a lot of oddities like this, where it makes perfect sense to a native speaker, but really throws off learners. There is a point for both native speakers and non-native speakers where you just have to accept that English does not always make sense, but there are conventions that people have accepted, and certain things, like this, make sense because of those conventions. I'd be happy to offer a better explanation if I can think of one!

Comment: I come across a lot of sentences daily that gain my curiosity, do you think you could help me out with some of them?
Are you ever on any of the chat groups here, like the ELL Cabin or the other one whose name i can't really remember?

Comment: I am not on the chats, I just browse this community occasionally and answer questions when I see them, but I would be more than happy to help you with these questions! You could either message me, or ask the question and send me the link so I can answer it for you and for others with the same question. If I become more active, I'll take a look at the chat groups!

Comment: i'll message you when i want to rid me of some doubts concerning certain constructions. :)

Comment: @redjax, how do i message you here?
I went on your profile, and there seemed no options that'd allow me text you or anything for that matter.

Comment: @lekonchekon hmm, it looks like you're right! I figured there was some way to message users, but maybe there is not. I guess the best way would be to comment on your post with a tag using my name (i.e. ask the question, and then comment something like "@redjax, you might have an answer for this" or something). I'll try to think of a simpler way to ask me questions!

Comment: Sure @redjax. 
Btw, i know how you joined the group, and were looking for me. 
I wasn't active in the group chat last day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37670/discussion-between-lekon-chekon-and-redjax).